# Can you explain what the AES paper means by "sharing active S-boxes"?

Tags: aes, cryptanalysis, biclique-attack

I am reading the "[Biclique cryptanalysis of the full AES](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/cryptanalysis/aesbc.pdf)" paper. What do they mean by *"sharing active S-boxes"*? How can this concept can be advantageous to make a bicycle? If there is someone who reads this paper, please explain it to me.

Comment: @e-sushi I don't think this is a reference request. It's asking for for clarification of certain concepts used in a notable paper. It's limited in scope and doesn't lead to link-only answers. So I consider it on topic.

Comment: Can you please provide a link to the paper and quote the relevant section here?

Answer (score 6):

We talk about cryptanalytic tools here. A [differential trail](http://csrc.nist.gov/archive/aes/rijndael/Rijndael-ammended.pdf)  describes how a certain difference evolutes throughout the cipher, which helps to find out a key in a standard differential cryptanalysis. Each trail activates certain non-linear operations (S-boxes), which contribute to its probability (a difference goes through a nonlinear operation probabilistically).

The [biclique key search method](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/cryptanalysis/aesbc.pdf) works with a pair of such trails in a small part of the cipher. For the method to work, these trails must activate non-interleaving groups of S-boxes, otherwise more sophisticated conditions come into play.